# CoreNLP Add Relations and other options?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I am using CoreNLP Built in API server to process some text for a small project.

using the [demo](http://corenlp.run/) I can see that they provide multiple options such as "relations", "wikipedia entities", "sentiment" and others.

[image: options corenlp]

However, After downloading coreNLP from the official website, Running the server on my local machine using the command: `java -d64 -mx8g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -timeout 500000`, I don't have the mentioned options. All i have is what's visible in this image:

[image: local image]

Unfortunately, I am not able to figure out how to add all the options available online to my local machine..

Can anyone please shed some light about what am I missing? How can i add the options? especially relations?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

These are recent additions that are in the [GitHub version of the code](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP), but not in the official 3.6.0 release.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, 
So you think If i download the github version and Compile it I'll get those features ? 

On another note, what's puzzling me is that the git version is only 62 MB ? While the compiled version is over 300 MB ?

Comment: Are you accounting for the models? There are two jars: one for the code, and another (much larger) one for the models.

Comment: I see. Forgive my ignorance - I'm still new to coreNLP and still trying to wrap my mind around it.

I'll try to figure out how to merge the whole thing and compile it. 
Is there any complete instruction link you know of? for newbies xD

Comment: Yup; as soon as it gets approved, I've started the stanford-nlp documentation page with some setup instructions for the official release, and building from GitHub source: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/stanford-nlp/4122/introduction-to-stanford-nlp . The sort version: run `ant jar` and it'll package the jar, and then download the models from http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-models-current.jar (warning: large download).

Comment: Great, 
I'll give it a shot. Thank you so much for the help

Comment: I downloaded the Model, I'm not sure its being loaded correctly tho.

I am using the classpath option such as:


java -classpath stanford-corenlp-models-current.jar -d64 -mx10g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -timeout 500000



how else can we use this model ? 
please let me know. 

Thanks

Comment: Update: 
The Reason i think its not loaded correctly is because im receiving exceptions on runtime such as :
(
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer$CoreNLPHandler.handle(StanfordCoreNLPServer.java:497)
        at...)